# jQuery change displayed price based on selected checkbox/radio button

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, localization, internationalization

On my WooCommerce site, visitors can add addons to a product that cost extra.

I am trying to update the displayed price on the product page based on the selected add on.

I got it to work partially but now I am stuck... In my code the calculation works, but I don't know how to make calculations using decimals too. (ex: 1.500,50 + 50 = 1.550,50)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var prijs = $('.price .amount').text().replace('€', '').replace(',', '');
$('.product-addon input').change(function(){
var x = $(this).closest('input:checked').value;
var total = prijs + x;
$('.price .amount').text(total);
});
});
```

This is how the html looks for the price field and radio button:

```html
<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>1,500.00</span></p>


<input type="radio" class="addon addon-radio" name="addon-401-kleur-0[]" data-raw-price="50" data-price="50" value="rood">
```

Resulting in the price to get updated from "€1,500.00" to "150050". Instead of the expected 1550.

Another thing.. how can I format the number to having decimals and the euro sign in front again? My basic code will output "1550" if it works, but I'd rather have it as "€1.550,00".

Hope someone can chime in ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `string`s together instead of `float`s. The values returned by `jQuery` are `string`s ([jQuery text() method](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text1)) and thus are being concatenated rather than being added together as numbers.

Have a look at [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Try doing something like:
`var prijs = parseFloat(...)`
and
`var x = parseFloat(...)`

Then in your `var total = prijs + x`, you will be adding two numbers together, which is what you want.

And as for formatting your numbers, have a look at [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

For example:

```
(1550).toLocaleString('en-GB', {style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).replace('£', '€');
```

Gives:

```
€1,550.00
```

Comment: Thank you! This led me to straight to my solution!